# can not understand backslash newline in bash double quotes

Tags: bash, shell

according to [gnu doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes),

> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of
>   the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within
>   double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these
>   characters are removed.

I tried

```
p="a\$b";echo $p  # a$b
p="a\`b";echo $p  # a`b
p="a\"b";echo $p  # a"b
p="a\\b";echo $p  # a\b
```

all is ok. But newline??

```
p="a\newlineb";echo $p  # a\newlineb
```

What does newline mean in the doc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newline is the name of the newline character, i.e. the character usually written as `\n` in C:

```
$ p="a\
b"; echo "$p"
ab
```

The result is `ab` rather than `\a<newline>b` since the [POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01):

> A `<backslash>` that is not quoted shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a `<newline>`. If a `<newline>` follows the `<backslash>` the shell shall interpret this as line continuation. The `<backslash>` and `<newline>` shall be removed before splitting the input into tokens. Since the escaped `<newline>` is removed entirely from the input and is not replaced by any white space, it cannot serve as a token separator.

But the string *is* quoted with double quotes... Well, this is a special case:

> The `<backslash>` shall retain its special meaning as an escape character only when followed by one of the following characters when considered special:
> `$`,   `` ` ``,   `"`,   `\`,   `<newline>`.

So the double-quoted string means that the backslash-newline is interpreted as if it was *not* quoted at all, which means it act as a line-continuation and both the backslash and newline are removed.

Note that this happens as you assign to the `p` variable, not when you `echo` it.

See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) about the neccecity of quoting your variables, always.

Comment: Is the output being shown `ab` ? Where has the newline vanished when the variable was quoted ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Please read updated answer.

Comment: Maybe also highlight the necessity of quoting the `echo` argument, though it doesn't particularly make a difference in this specific case.

Comment: @sorontar Thanks for the edit, but I've replaced it with a POSIX ref instead. :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda That is perfectly correct and valid (also for bash), so no complaints, instead: Many thanks :).