# Newlines not getting printed in bash

Tags: bash

Why are newlines not printed when calling `echo "$var"` ?

```
chart ()
 {
  local var="
 find ~/Opstk/bin/gadin-1.0/ -name '*.rc' -exec \
   grep -C MYVAR {} \+"

  echo "$var"
 }
```

Comment: What newlines? There is one newline in your string (at the start), and `echo` adds another one at the end.  Also, just because it feels like this will be the next question: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Comment: The current question is most likely a duplicate of [can not understand backslash newline in bash double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359509)

Comment: I think you figures the problem.  That the inclusion of `\\` puts the echo on same line.